# Altering Specific Text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML/PHP:

```
<p>
    <span data-good="<?php echo $row['good']; ?>" data-wasVoted="<?php echo $row['wasVoted']; ?>" data-review="<?php echo $row['review_id']; ?>"  class="upvote">Votes (<span class="good"><?php echo $row['good']; ?></span>)</span>
</p>
```

This looks like a mess, I apologize but it is test code.

To the user this will look like this in the output:

```
Votes (3) // 3 is just an example number.
```

This will be clickable.  I want the user to click on it, and if they have already voted on this, 3 becomes 2.  If they have not, 3 becomes 4.    This is determined by the `data-wasVoted` attribute.  It is 1 if they have and 0 if they haven't.  (there will be styling so user can identify if they have upvoted or not).

Sending this info to server and getting back what I need is all set up.  I just can't figure out a good way to grab the right number since this is a looped list of generated HTML.  So there are a string of dynamic vote buttons.

Here is my jQuery:

```
var review_id = $(this).data('review');
var was_voted = $(this).data('wasVoted');
var vote_total = $(this).data('good');

var new_text = $('.good');


$.ajax({
        url : "php/reviews_upvote.php",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {
            reviewId : review_id
        },
        success : function(data) {

            if (was_voted == 1) {
                vote_total = vote_total - 1;
                new_text.text(vote_total);
            } else {
                vote_total = vote_total + 1;
                new_text.text(vote_total);
            }

        }
    });
```

**The first problem** is obviously the var `new_text`.  It's based on a `class` that  is repeated over and over again.  So if you click one, ALL vote numbers change on the page, not just the one you are dealing with.  How can I identify the unique attribute of the one I need?

**The second issue;** since a user can only vote one -- I need to dynamically change the `was_voted` var to 0 if it was 1, or 1 if it was 0.

**EDIT:**  Added HTML rendered after `php` is called.

```
<span data-good="2" data-wasvoted="1" data-review="2582"  class="upvote">
    Votes (<span class="good">2</span>)
</span>
```

`data-good` is the vote total.

Comment: This ajax call happens when you click on it right. To resolve the 1st problem use `this` to target the element

Comment: The second issue can also be solved with `this`, `$(this).prev(".upvotes").attr("data-wasVoted", newNumber);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the logic is handled inside the click event .

**1st Problem** - Use this to target the element.

**2nd Problem** - Use the same context to change the data attribute

```
var $this = $(this),
    review_id = $this.data('review'),
    was_voted = $this.data('wasVoted'),
    vote_total = $this.data('good'),

    new_text = $('.good');

$.ajax({
        url : "php/reviews_upvote.php",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {
            reviewId : review_id
        },
        success : function(data) {

            if (was_voted == 1) {
                vote_total = vote_total - 1;
                $this.data('wasVoted', 0);
            } else {
                vote_total = vote_total + 1;
                $this.data('wasVoted', 1);
            }
            $this.find('.good').text(vote_total);

        }
    });
```

Comment: How would you add `this` to `var new_text = $('.good');`? `$(this).$(.good)` maybe?

Comment: You would do `$(this).find('.good')`.. Also you need to keep ware of the `this` context inside the success callback

Comment: I am trying to solve #2 like this `$(this).find('.upvote').attr("data-wasvoted", "1");` but this doesn't seem to work?  Any advice?

Comment: On which element is the click event defined.. The selector might change based on it.. And if possible can you just paste the rendered `HTML` after removing the php code

Comment: ok, added the code;  the outside `<span class="upvote">` is the click that `jQuery` looks for.

Comment: Then `$(this).data('wasvoted', 1)` should do.. You need to cache your `this` inside the success callback , as this refers to xhr object inside it..

Comment: Ok; that code seems like that should work (based on api ref of `data(key, value)`), but it doesn't.  I assume its because I am not caching `this` then? Apologies for asking the obvious question, how is that done?  Appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Check the post above.. I use var `$this = $(this)` to cache it and use $this inside the success handler

Comment: Hey thanks, just after I typed that, I came up with something like that and have it working. Thanks! Marking correct.

Comment: @KickingLettuce.. glad to have helped :)